# How to count the number of words in a website using tm package with R?

Tags: r, string, text, text-mining

Hello i am trying to use the tm package to count  the number  of words in my web site to have an estimation of the cost of it's translation.

Have anyone tried to do something similar using R?

Comment: Personally, I'd create a data crawler of some sort and not use R. I'd like to see an answer to this as well..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringi` package to count words:

```
require(stringri)
stri_stats_latex("Ala ma kota a kot ma Ale.")
    CharsWord CharsCmdEnvir    CharsWhite         Words          Cmds        Envirs 
           18             0             7             7             0             0
```

Comment: I would add to this example elimination of stop words which aren't really taken into consideration in costs of translation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad and you haven't shown what you have tried to do.  Nor did you say how many pages your website has (or give its URL), but if it is a manageable number, you could do something like this:

Use the `RCurl` or `httr` packages to scrape everything from each page.

Then with the `tm` package remove all HTML codes (or `qdap` might help)

Convert the remaining text to a corpus and a term document matrix (tdm).

With the tdm, `nTerms(tdm)` will tell you the number of words

Comment: Good luck!  Post your code as an edit and others will undoubtedly improve on these ideas.  The more you show, the more help you will get.

Comment: If this met your needs, consider accepting it as an answer.